# Querying a MySQL database to show properties within a certain radius of a UK postcode using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have a MySQL table containing a list of properties in the UK. The table contains the full address of each property including the post code. I need to be able to query the database to show all properties within a certain radius (e.g. 3 miles) of a given post code.

I've searched SO and couldn't find a similar question.

Research on Google seems to suggest I need to use Google Maps but I can't find any material to get me going. I don't need to display the results on a map at this stage, a simple list of the properties will suffice.

I'm not asking for someone to code this for me (although that would be nice!), I'm just after a point in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you need access to some kind of database of coordinates corresponding to the centroids of the given postcodes

Comment: I found my solution here; https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 with a little help from here; http://stanhub.com/get-latitude-longitude-coordinates-from-postcode-address-using-google-api-display-google-map/

Answer (score 0):

If your properties are already accounted on the Google Server the Google Places API would be able to retrieve them. You just need to set the radius of 3 miles as parameter.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

More details related to the parameter passed can be found in this official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

If these places are not accounted in Google than they wont be displayed after requesting this REST API. Then you have to follow the standard procedure of:

- Creating a query of fetching the requesting the address in within 3 miles with given postal address.
  Select address from table where radius=3 & postalCode=xxxxx;
- When you have the address convert them into Lat/Lng using Geocoder API.
- Finally display them on Google Maps.

Hope this helps!!